# Trouble compiling GDB with python 2.7 support for gdb-peda

Tags: python-2.7, gdb

Trying to install gdb-peda, but am having issues compiling gdb with python 2 support instead of python 3 support.
I have

```
python-dev for 2.7, 
build-dep nmon,
and libncurses5-dev
```

installed. I installed gdb-peda before I uninstalled and subsequently compiled gdb.

```
~/gdb-7.8$ ./configure --with-python
~/gdb-7.8$ make all
~/gdb-7.8$ sudo make install
```

GDB installs without errors (after I installed the necessary libraries), but when I run it I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/peda/peda.py", line 23, in <module>
Exception: Python3 is not supported at the moment, downgrade you GDB or recompile with Python2!
```

This is the same error I got before I reinstalled gdb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easier way to install `gdb` with Python 2.7 support is:

```
sudo apt-get remove gdb
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gdb/gdb_7.4-2012.02-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i ./gdb_7.4-2012.02-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Substitute `i386` for `amd64` if necessary.

The first line removes the current gdb version. The second will download gdb from a previous version. And the last line installs it.

Answer (score 1):

**For this issue you are having 2 ways:**

> Recompile GDB --with-python=python2  (or) Downgrade GDB.

For downgrading you need one mirror support older GDB: http://virror.hanoilug.org/ubuntu/virror_precise_sources.list
You need synaptic. Search GDB, chose Package/Force Version/Chose 7.4. **Confirm and install now.**

Comment: Where do I save that file to?

Comment: Not sure where to save this file to: http://virror.hanoilug.org/ubuntu/virror_precise_sources.list. If I just left it in my downloads folder, synaptic didn't list 7.4 as an option.

Answer (score 1):

You can install [`another version`](https://github.com/zachriggle/peda) what has been extended by [Zach Riggle](https://github.com/zachriggle) to add some features and give dual-compatibility with Python2 and Python3.